# How to plot array shape (4, 4, 4, 5, 5) onto a 2d figure with matplotlib?

Tags: python, matplotlib

with `gridspec.GridSpecFromSubplotSpec` in `matplotlib`, I managed to plot an array with shape (4, 4, 5, 5) into 4 subplots (each is a small figure with 4 images with width and height being 5) onto a larger 2d figure.

I wonder how to plot array with shape (4, 4, 4, 5, 5) (each subplot is a figure like described above) onto a larger 2d figure?

see illustration below: I managed to plot level 1-3, but I don't know how to plot level4. Could anyone help? Thanks
[image]

Comment: Show your code that you managed to plot level 1-3

Comment: thanks, when I finished writing up what I can do up to level3, I realize the question is answered too.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for asking me to write codes for plotting array with shape (4,4,5,5), when I made it work with simpler dataset, I realize I can plot (4,4,4,5,5) too.

Below are codes to plot arrays with shape (4,4,5,5) and (4,4,4,5,5)

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.gridspec as gridspec
import math
import numpy as np

#### plot (4,4,5,5)
data_4d = np.linspace(0, 1, 400).reshape((4,4,5,5))
num_out_img, num_inner_img, img_w, img_h = data_4d.shape

fig = plt.figure(1, figsize=(6, 6))

outer_grid = math.ceil(math.sqrt(num_out_img))
inner_grid = math.ceil(math.sqrt(num_inner_img))

outer_frame = gridspec.GridSpec(outer_grid, outer_grid)

for sub in range(num_out_img):

    inner_frame = gridspec.GridSpecFromSubplotSpec(inner_grid, inner_grid, subplot_spec=outer_frame[sub], wspace=0.0, hspace=0.0)

    for sub_sub in range(num_inner_img):

        ax = plt.Subplot(fig, inner_frame[sub_sub])
        ax.imshow(data_4d[sub, sub_sub, :, :], cmap='gray')
        fig.add_subplot(ax)

plt.show()

#### plot (4,4,4,5,5)
data_5d = np.linspace(0, 1, 1600).reshape((4,4,4,5,5))
num_out_img, num_inner_img, num_deep_img, img_w, img_h = data_5d.shape

fig = plt.figure(1, figsize=(6, 6))

outer_grid = math.ceil(math.sqrt(num_out_img))
inner_grid = math.ceil(math.sqrt(num_inner_img))
deep_grid = math.ceil(math.sqrt(num_deep_img))

outer_frame = gridspec.GridSpec(outer_grid, outer_grid)

for sub in range(num_out_img):

    inner_frame = gridspec.GridSpecFromSubplotSpec(inner_grid, inner_grid, subplot_spec=outer_frame[sub], wspace=0.0, hspace=0.0)

    for sub_sub in range(num_inner_img):

        deep_frame = gridspec.GridSpecFromSubplotSpec(deep_grid, deep_grid, subplot_spec=inner_frame[sub_sub], wspace=0.0, hspace=0.0)

        for deep in range(num_deep_img):

            ax = plt.Subplot(fig, deep_frame[deep])
            ax.imshow(data_5d[sub, sub_sub, deep, :, :], cmap='gray')
            fig.add_subplot(ax)

plt.show()
```